# Существует ли в C++ макрос с именем класса?

Tags: c++, логирование, макросы, макрос

Пишу самописный модуль для ведения журнала работы программы. Для упрощения последующего анализа логов хочу сделать разбивку сообщений по группам/модулям, для чего вполне подойдёт использовать названия классов. Для получения названия функции существует `__FUNCTION__`, а есть ли макрос для имени класса?

Comment: А как вы себе представляете его применение?...

Comment: @Harry Видимо чтобы в логах было подписано, из какого класса их печатали?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Т.е. из **функции** класса? Для этого есть `__FUNCTION__`. Груго говоря, **куда** вставлять макрос `__CLASS__`? Ну вот представим, что он есть - покажите пример применения, что вы хотите (это уже к ТС)?

Comment: Ну, к примеру, есть у меня два класса - `Class1` и `Class2`. Если вызов макроса логирования был сделан из `Class1`- `__CLASS__` должен содержать `Class1`, а если из `Class2` - то `Class2`. Что непонятного? Чуть позже накидаю пример.

Comment: Вот как-то так: https://pastebin.com/bsNQiNHY

Comment: `LOG("MyClass1","Message")`, в крайнем случае `LOG(typeid(*this).name(),"Message")`.